# Groovy/Grails : How to sort the map with order given in separate list

Tags: sorting, groovy

I have a given list of data :

```
  def given  = [
  [Country:'Japan',Flag:'Yes',Event:'New Year'],
  [Country:'china',Flag:'No',Event:'Spring Festival'],
  [Country:'uk',Flag:'No',Event:'National Holiday'],
  [Country:'us',Flag:'Yes',Event:'Labour Day'],
  [Country:'us',Flag:'Yes',Event:'New Year'],
  [Country:'uk',Flag:'Yes',Event:'Memorial Day']
]
```

I can sort using groovy sort method :

```
given = given.collect().sort { a, b  ->
  a.Flag <=> b.Flag ?: a.Event <=> b.Event 
}
```

but, how would i do it if the sort by is mentioned by user and stored in separate list like 
eg : def `sortOrder = ["Country","Flag"]`, Here sort Order is dynamic that is users choice : `["Country","Flag"] / ["Country","Flag","Event"]` or none. How can i write sort method so that it takes my dynamic arguments in closure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your custom order in a variable `order`, try

```
given.sort { a, b ->
    order.inject(0) { o, e -> 
        o ?: a[e] <=> b[e]
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks, it worked for me  a little modification @tim_yates         `given.sort { a, b ->
            sortOrder.inject(0) { o, e ->
                    o != 0 ? o : a[e] <=> b[e]
            }
        }`

Comment: You shouldn't need that, might be orator precedence if it was failing, ie: `o ?: (a[e] <=> b[e])`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to iterate the sortorder and use `findResult` to get the "ufo" results. The ugly part about this, is that `findResults` does not use groovy truth and `sort` needs an int, so some elvis action is needed to.  e.g.

```
def given  = [[Country:'Japan',Flag:'Yes',Event:'New Year'],
    [Country:'china',Flag:'No',Event:'Spring Festival'],
    [Country:'uk',Flag:'No',Event:'National Holiday'],
    [Country:'us',Flag:'Yes',Event:'Labour Day'],
    [Country:'us',Flag:'Yes',Event:'New Year'],
    [Country:'uk',Flag:'Yes',Event:'Memorial Day']]

def sortorder = ['Flag', 'Event']

assert given.sort{ a,b -> 
    sortorder.findResult{ a[it] <=> b[it] ?: null }  ?: 0
}.first()==[Country:'uk', Flag:'No', Event:'National Holiday']
```